# Not able to load com.github.smarteist.autoimageslider:1.4.0

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-library

Getting red underline while adding `com.Smarteist.autoimageslider.slideview` in **XML** file in Android Studio. How to resolve?

It's showing:
`Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':Could not resolve com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0`

Comment: According to their [github](https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider), if you're using **appcompat**, then you should have this instead: `implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'`. Are you using **appcompat** libraries by any chance?

Answer (score 8):

check if jcenter() is missing in your build.gradle, if add it.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //here
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
   
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cNT6.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dependencies in dependencyResolutionManagement inside settings.gradle.

As of the 7.X.X gradle build tools. allprojects is deprecated use of dependencyResolutionManagement is the best practice for declaring repositories.

Because of this Android projects will no longer generate with allprojects blocks in their project build.gradle files. It will instead generate a **dependencyResolutionManagement** block in **settings.gradle**.

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        // e.g this is how you would add jitpack
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // Add any repositories you would be adding to all projects here
    }
}
```